# shp2pgsql throws "ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block"

Tags: postgis, postgresql, shp2pgsql

I am trying to upload a shapefile to postgres using the command :

```
shp2pgsql -I -s 4326 "/Users/abc/Landmark.shp" table_name | psql -U user_name --dbname=db_name
```

I get the error :

> ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of
>   transaction block
>   ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands
>   ignored until end of transaction block
>   ROLLBACK
>   ANALYZE

Postgis extension is added to the user postgres.
Not sure what is it that I am missing here.

Comment: The error will be before all of what you have pasted. Use, ON_ERROR_STOP, and pipe std_err to std_out and you will see it.

Comment: I'm also getting a similar error